# Add file to repository in post-commit hook

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

Is it possible to add new file to Repository in post-commit hooks.

When users commit files, the new file has to be added to the repository which contains commit comments given by the user.

For second time commit of same file needs to append the file which already added.

Can I do this by using `svn.exe add` command?

Comment: Why do you even need this? Why not `svn log`?

Answer (score 1):

Check the [SVNBook](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/reposadmin/create/) for the answer:

> **Warning**
>
> While hook scripts can do almost anything, there is one dimension in
>   which hook script authors should show restraint: do not modify a
>   commit transaction using hook scripts. While it might be tempting to
>   use hook scripts to automatically correct errors, shortcomings, or
>   policy violations present in the files being committed, doing so can
>   cause problems. Subversion keeps client-side caches of certain bits of
>   repository data, and if you change a commit transaction in this way,
>   those caches become indetectably stale. This inconsistency can lead to
>   surprising and unexpected behavior. Instead of modifying the
>   transaction, you should simply validate the transaction in the
>   pre-commit hook and reject the commit if it does not meet the desired
>   requirements. As a bonus, your users will learn the value of careful,
>   compliance-minded work habits.